# userDn and Password are needed for autentication type - None or not

Tags: oracle, spring-security, ldap, spring-security-ldap

Am Developing an application in Spring MVC & JPA with Spring Security. Now Integrating the OUD (Oracle Unified Directory) through LDAP. If the authentication type is none. Is there is any need for userDn and Password

```
<bean id="contextSource" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource">
    <constructor-arg value="ldaps://192.168.0.182:1636/o=company"/>
    <property name="userDn" value="cn=userid,ou=groups,o=company"/>
    <property name="password" value="password"/>
</bean>
```

I am new to LDAP. To my understanding userDn and Password is needed when the authentication type is simple.

Pl.help me to understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct: authentication type `none` implies a so-called *anonymous bind* where you access the LDAP directory without authentication and with public rights. 
Typically, this is used to resolve a username into the full *Distinguished Name* (DN) of the user that is logging in. A DN is usually of the form `CN=user,OU=department,O=organization`

For any other authentication types, you will need that DN of the user logging in, and a credential. When you are accessing Active Directory you may also log in using the *User Principal Name* of the form `user@domain`. Don't encourage that :-/

Comment: Thanks @mvreijn. What is the purpose of userdn and password in constructor. Because if the type is simple we are passing values through security_authentication, security_principal, security_credentials right

Comment: The user and password for the context are used for searching and resolving information like groups and memberships. A proxy user so to speak.

Comment: These values we are passing through  env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "cn=userid,ou=groups,o=company");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "password"); in file. Is there is any other need

Comment: Since you are providing the full DN during authentication, just try without the fixed credentials in the bean configuration.